# Adding a toolbar to a table following HTML semantics

Tags: html, markup, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I have a basic HTML table like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add a toolbar above it. Would it be semantically acceptable to add a toolbar as a row in the `thead`?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <!-- toolbar buttons -->
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using a table in the first place?

Comment: Are the toolbar buttons related to the data in the table?

Comment: Diodeus, I'm displaying tabular data.

Comment: Kevin, yes, the toolbar buttons are directly related to the content of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, since the toolbar is related to the tabular data, I see no semantic issue with having that toolbar live in a row in the `thead`.